# Prevent Users from Using Standard/Uncustomized Forms in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, forms, netsuite

Do you know any Suitescript code example that will prevent users from using the standard/uncustomized forms? We have a lot of custom forms in our netsuite account and each of these forms have mandatory fields needed for our reporting. However, the users are able to skip these fields by choosing the standard/uncustomized forms. Is there a way to prohibit using these forms for all roles excel administrator and full access roles without going to each role and disabling the standard/uncustomized forms? I'll appreciate any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a script. You just need to do a workflow instead.
Preventive solution: Before USER submit, do not allow to user to save if they are using the Standard/Uncustomized form.

Before RECORD Load, if User Role = ROLE A then... Set Field Value; Custom Form to the desired form. This is except for Admin and Full Access role.
Before RECORD Load, if User Roles = ROLE A then... Set Display Type: Custom Form to DISABLE. This is except for Admin and Full Access role.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, the way to do this is to go to each role and disable the standard/uncustomized forms.

That's the best practice.

Comment: thanks Jo..that's also the advice of the netsuite rep, I think I have to study javascript to find out if it can be done thru a script..

Comment: Why is it easier to write a script than to fix the roles?

Would you have the script open the customized form when the user tries to open the standard form?

Comment: yeah I prefer a script because of the following reasons:
1. it's much difficult to navigate to the script than to navigate in the roles (in case users want to override the controls I placed)
2. I'm just using a full access role, we have 2 administrators and and bunch of roles that have access to managing roles.

Answer (score 0):

For most standard forms you can mark them inactive.  Inactive forms cannot be selected by users.